# loading a form onto a panel without autosizing the form

Tags: c#

I'm trying to open a form in a panel,but whenever it loads, the form re-sizes in the panel, or maybe the panel re-sizes, which i do not want.

my parent form is of bigger resolution than the child form
the panel too is bigger than the child form(similar size of the parent form)
(on running the project, both the panel and the form gets re-sized to a smaller size than the parent window)
what should i do?

Comment: Could you give us more info like your code..

Comment: Registration.MainRegistration ma;
public MainForm()
{
InitializeComponent();
ma = new Registration.MainRegistration();
}
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
tabRegistration.Show();
ma.TopLevel = false;ma.Visible = true;
panel1.Controls.Add(ma);
}

Comment: dont post code in comments.. update your question.

Comment: and why aren't your using user controls instead of forms?  or MDI?

Comment: @jestin_jose don't use forms as user controls, instead of that use UserControl.

Comment: You can set the form's AutoScaleMode property to None.  This is *very* unlikely what you really want.  It does however have to great advantage that you'll now understand why it is important that it works this way.